# How to retrieve pdf files from the server

Tags: php, server, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

Assume I have Website which have a collection of pdf books. Now I want to make a telegram bot to search book and retriever to the telegram bot.

I have tried this code but not getting messages in telegram bot

```
// Include the Telegram bot API library

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Telegram\Bot\Api;

// Create a new instance of the Telegram bot API

$telegram = new Api('YOUR_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN_HERE');

// Function to search for books in your database

function search_books($query) {

    // Replace the database credentials with your own

    $servername = "localhost";

    $username = "username";

    $password = "password";

    $dbname = "database_name";

    // Create a new MySQL connection

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check the connection

    if ($conn->connect_error) {

        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

    }

    // Prepare the SQL query

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, title FROM books WHERE title LIKE ? OR author LIKE ?");

    // Bind the search query to the query string

    $search_query = "%" . $query . "%";

    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $search_query, $search_query);

    // Execute the SQL query

    $stmt->execute();

    // Get the result set

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    // Initialize an empty array to store the matching books

    $books = array();

    // Loop through the result set and add each book to the array

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $books[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'title' => $row['title']);

    }

    // Close the database connection

    $conn->close();

    // Return the array of matching books

    return $books;

}

// Register a command handler for the /search command

$telegram->addCommand('search', function ($message) use ($telegram) {

    // Get the search query from the message text

    $query = str_replace('/search ', '', $message->getText());

    // Search for books in the database

    $books = search_books($query);

    // Generate a response message with the search results

    $response = "Search results for '$query':\n";

    foreach ($books as $book) {

        $response .= "• " . $book['title'] . "\n";

    }

    // Send the response message to the user

    $chat_id = $message->getChat()->getId();

    $telegram->sendMessage(['chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => $response]);

});

// Register a default handler for unsupported commands

$telegram->addCommand('unsupported', function ($message) use ($telegram) {

    // Generate an error message

    $response = "Sorry, I don't understand that command. Please try again.";

    // Send the error message to the user

    $chat_id = $message->getChat()->getId();

    $telegram->sendMessage(['chat_id' => $chat_id, 'text' => $response]);

});

// Start listening for incoming messages

$telegram->commandsHandler(
);
```